# constructor.Invoke(parameters) is giving me an error

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, system.reflection

I'm trying to invoke an instance using constructor.Invoke and also passing some parameters in it, but I'm getting

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Any inputs would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Look at the diagnostic output for the exception, rather than just the message. It will include an InnerException with more details.

Comment: Can you please share some code of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

`TargetInvocationException` basically means that the member could be invoked successfully and the exception occurred in the invoked member itself. To differentiate it from other issues (eg. wrong instance, invalid number or type of parameters, etc.) the exception thrown by the invoked member is wrapped into a `TargetInvocationException`. Just look at its `InnerException` to see what happened.

If you want to 'unwrap' such exceptions as if you called the constructor without reflection you can do something like this:

```cs
try
{
    return myConstructorInfo.Invoke(parameters);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException e)
{
    // we could just throw e.InnerException but that would corrupt the
    // original stack trace, showing this line as the source of the exception
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e.InnerException).Throw();
    throw; // unreachable, just to satisfy the compiler if there is no return later
}
```